# read_csv with parse_date not recognising dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
date,important
July 2015,True
August 2015,False
```

But when I try to read it into pandas using [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with the `parse_dates` flag, it isn't parsing the date column as dates:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=True)
df
          date important
0    July 2015      True
1  August 2015     False
```

I guess this is because they aren't date objects in a recognised format, but is there any way around this?

I can use `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)` just fine, so I find it odd that I can't do that on import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it parses the index as date and there is no index specified here. Either pass `index_col=0` or specify the name of the column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['date'])

df
Out[30]: 
        date important
0 2015-07-01      True
1 2015-08-01     False
```

Or

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

df
Out[33]: 
           important
date                
2015-07-01      True
2015-08-01     False
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea. Thanks.